# What are the periodic Dirichlet series?

Tags: dirichlet-series

My **question** is: What are the periodic Dirichlet series? Does the Riemann zeta function $ζ(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}$ and the alternating zeta function   $η(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)ⁿ⁻¹/n^{s}$ are periodic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in that [thesis](http://www.imsc.res.in/xmlui/handle/123456789/337?show=full) by Tapas Chatterjee, where you find the answer is yes for  both the Riemann zeta function and the alternating zeta function.

Comment: Why would you link to a PhD thesis to answer this?

Comment: @ user64494: Since you read this thesis, can you indicate to me the page where this fact was presented.

Comment: @AR1 : p.21, lines 6-8.

Comment: @ user64494: Thank you very much.

Comment: @ Pedro Tamaroff: That is easily  accessible through the Internet.

Comment: You didn't answer to the question : what is a periodic Dirichlet series. Here it means the coefficients are $q$-periodic so $$\Gamma(s) \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s} = \int_0^\infty x^{s-1} \frac{\sum_{n=1}^q a_n e^{-nx}}{1-e^{-qx}}dx$$ also giving a functional equation in term of $\sum_{m=1}^q a_m \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{2i \pi m n/ q} n^{-s}$